# ASP.NET MVC 5 project shows "Source map error (404)" for bootstrap (css and js)

Tags: css, asp.net, bootstrap-4, source-maps

I've added Bootstrap into my ASP.NET MVC 5 project. When I open the debugger, I get the following:

```
Source map error: request failed with status 404
Resource URL: http://localhost:123456/css/libraries?v=xxxxxxx
Source Map URL: bootstrap.min.css.map
```

Now this is happening because the debugger can't find the Bootstrap source map file inside my bundle. The map file is definitely there under `/Content` (I can browse to it), but the browser can't find it because clearly the bundle and the physical path are different.

I know these can be safely ignored, but I'd rather fix the problem (without editing third party library files).

What is the best way to include these .map files so they are found under my bundle name? Basically, is there an ASP.NET bundle way of exposing `/Content/bootstrap.min.css.map` as `/css/libraries/bootstrap.min.css.map`?

Comment: I'd love an answer to this :D

Comment: I never got a solution unfortunately :( Because it was an internal project I just left it as it was.